# Swing load available font family slow down the performance

Tags: swing, performance

After I add in this code to load the available font family and add it in to combobox

```
 GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.
  getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
String[] fontNames = ge.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
```

It load very slow took about 7 seconds to show the page when i trigger the page. After i take it out it load fine as normal. Is there any solution, any people faceing the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The delay is due to the fact that `getAvailableFontFamilyNames` creates a 1 pt font for every font it can find. It allows the JVM to distinguish between fonts it can use and things that only *look* like they may be fonts.

The best approach is to call it in a `SwingWorker` and then update the combo from the `done` method.

**update:**
The poster's code updated to use the generified SwingWorker.
Note: I am returning the array of names as it eliminates the need for synchronization.

```
SwingWorker aWorker<String[],Void> = new SwingWorker<String[],Void>() {
    protected void done() { 
        String[] fontNames = get();
        for (int i = 0; i < fontNames.length; i++) 
            fontFamily.addItem(fontNames[i]);
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground() throws Exception {
        GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
        return env.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(); 
    }
};
aWorker.run();
```

Comment: Hi i do it in this way is it correct? 
  SwingWorker aWorker = new SwingWorker() {
   String[] fontNames = null;
   public Object construct() {

    return null;
   }

   protected void done() {
    for (int i = 0; i < fontNames.length; i++)
     fontFamily.addItem(fontNames[i]);
   }

   @Override
   protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
    GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment
      .getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    fontNames = env.getAvailableFontFamilyNames();
    return null;
   }
  };
  aWorker.run();

Answer (score 0):

Just load it in the background () when you app starts. By the time user opens the page it will be loaded.