# Adding custom fonts takes too much time

Tags: java, performance, fonts, awt, java-7

My Java-application needs some custom fonts to create its GUI (to look *extra* good). They are being read in from a "source-folder" (resource) by:

```
try(InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream(path)) {

    ge.registerFont(
       Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, resourceStream)
    );

} catch(IOException | FontFormatException e) {
    // ...
}
```

This process takes ~5 seconds per font, which is quite a bit. It gets especially annoying when you're developing, needing to start a new instance of the program quite often.

**Is there any way to reduce the time it takes to add a custom font?**

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3237941/778118

Comment: I would recommend using [`Font.createFont(int,InputStream)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Font.html#createFont%28int,%20java.io.InputStream%29) to load fonts because that `File` will likely vanish by time of deployment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Very valid point, completely forgot that. Thanks!

Comment: It is still taking a long time using the `InputStream`?

Comment: @AndrewThompson Bit shorter time now (approx. 1s shorter / font), still taking ~4s / font though.

Comment: *"still taking ~4s / font though."*  Hmm.. not good.  I wonder if this is dependent on the JRE version.  Could you try it in other JREs?  If this is a regression bug, we'll need to get it fixed.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Seems to be equally slow running Java 6. Can you reproduce this using Java 7?

Comment: Prepare an SSCCE and I might look into it.